# Docker compose permission denied with volume

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have the following `docker-compose` file:

```yaml
version: "3.8"

services:
  api:
    image: myuser/myimage
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/app/static
      - /home/deployer/config_files/gunicorn.py:/app/gunicorn.py
      - /home/deployer/log_files:/app/log_files
    env_file:
      - /home/deployer/config_files/api.env
    expose:
      - 8000

  nginx:
    image: myuser/nginximage
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/app/static
      - /home/deployer/config_files/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf
    ports:
      - 80:80
    depends_on:
      - api

volumes:
  static_volume:
```

The `api` service was built using the following docker file (summarized to reduce size):

```
FROM python:3.9.1

WORKDIR /app

# Copy code etc into container
COPY ./api/ .
COPY entrypoint.sh .

# create static and log files directories
RUN mkdir static
RUN mkdir log_files

# create non root user, change ownership of all files, switch to this user
RUN adduser --system --group appuser
RUN chown -R appuser:appuser /app
USER appuser

CMD [ "/app/entrypoint.sh" ]
```

If I remove `/home/deployer/log_files:/app/log_files` from the compose file everything works correctly. However I am trying to use that log files directory for `gunicorn` to use for log files. Including that line results in the following error when `docker-compose up`:

`Error: Error: '/app/log_files/gunicorn_error.log' isn't writable [PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied')]`

On the linux host I am running `docker-compose up` with the user named `deployer`. Inside the container as per the Dockerfile I created a user called `appuser`. I'm guessing this is related to the issue but I'm not sure.

Basically all I'm trying to do is to have log files inside the container be accessible outside the container so that they persist even if the server is restarted.

Comment: What are the permissions of /home/deployer/log_files?

Comment: drwxr-xr-x 2 deployer deployers 4096 Feb  2 07:03 log_files

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`/app/log_files` is still owned by `deployers` user inside your container and `appuser` does not have permission to write to it. As per your comment, it seems `/home/deployer/log_files` is owned by `deployer:deployers` with permission `drwxr-xr-x`. The permissions will be the same for `/app/log_files` inside container as per bind mount.

Even if `deployers` user does not exists in your container it will still be owned by the UID of `deployers` user (you can check this by running `ls` from inside the container).

You can:

- Add world-writable permission to `/home/deployer/log_files` such as

  ```
  chmod 777 /home/deployer/log_files
  ```

  This may present a security risk though, other solution is a bit more complex but better.
- Retrieve or set the UID of `appuser` and set ownership of `/home/deployer/log_files` to this user. For example in Dockerfile create `appuser` with specific UID `1500`:

  ```
  RUN adduser -u 1500 --system --group appuser
  ```

  And from your host change directory owner to this UID

  ```
  sudo chown 1500:1500 /home/deployer/log_files
  ```

  At container runtime, `appuser` (UID `1500`) will then be able to write to this directory

More generally, you should ensure `/home/deployer/log_files` is writable by the user running inside the container while keeping it's access secure if needed.